# Ratchet session

Tags: symfony, session, ratchet

I have the issue with `Ratchet` (Symfony2) session. It looks like Ratchet checks the session only when opening connection, while for example if session expires while the client is connected, `$conn->Session` still contains data of the old session.

I use PDO session handler to share session data between my symfony website and Ratchet server. When I delete session from the database before the client connects then Ratchet detects that session does not exist, but, if the client connects and then I delete session from the database - Ratchet does not "see" that session does not exist anymore and `$conn->Session` contains old variables.

It is a very troublesome, because for example, user could logout from the site (or the session may simply expire) while the client is connected and since Ratchet is not aware that the session is destroyed we cannot rely on session.

Comment: i have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821199/ratchet-session-data-syncronisation-using-memcache i am trying to fix it by ask my database if the sessionid is valid in my ratchet onMessage handler...